# Vuetify components import issue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, laravel-mix

I'm trying to import vuetify to the existing vue project. Laravel is used as a backend.

**Laravel-mix webpack.mix.js file:**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
```

**Basic app.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import App from './App'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**App.vue:**

```
<template>
  <v-app>

  </v-app>
</template>
```

While accessing web page vue generates an error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-app> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <App> at /var/www/project/resources/assets/App.vue
       <Root>
```

So it looks like vue can't find veutify vApp component, however i see that vuetify code as well as its components code included in compilled app.js.
Probably there is a miss-configuration of webpack.mix.js.

Please advise what should be also checked, especially in terms of laravelmix-vue-vuetify bunch?

Comment: Can you find $vuetify inside main vue instance?

Comment: @AnkitKumarOjha looks like it's undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not been attentive. vue was imported twice:
1. in html via `<script src>`
2. in app.js via import

After removing `<script src>` issue has gone.